# Range limit of a variable

Tags: range

How can I code for these conditions

> If E is greater than 10 limit E to 10
>
> If the equation is E = 10 x C/D

Basically how to set a limit for the value of E

Comment: `E = min(10 * C /D, 10)`?

Comment: tried that but it doesnt find symbol min

Comment: what programming language are you using?